# Extract HTML source of a web page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, information-retrieval

I use this code to extract a web page htm source code:

```
    private static string GetWebText(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return htmlText;
    }
```

after i use this code to extract the source code of this page(==>extract hrefs):

http://www.bayt.com/en/qatar/jobs/

when i've got my html source code,i didn't find a lot of content like :
"Cost Optimization Adviser"

is it because it's a server side generated content?

How can I change my code so that it brings the html source code with server side generated content included?

Comment: are you trying to scrape their data to another website? make sure you have legal agreements with them, and if you have, you might ask them for an export of the contents in a more simple form like XML.

regarding your problem, if they use AJAX to load the contents async, then that might be your problem

Comment: Thanks BerggreenDK.Why when i do "show source code",i get all the content?

Comment: are you sure you dont get parsed DOM version? thats the one containing whats compiled after every script has run.

Comment: how can i get the parsed dom version,i m getting from <<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC..> to </html>

Comment: Essentially "be a browser" - parse the document with an HTML reader and JS engine. This is absolutely non-trivial, and one of the reasons content is so often generated beyond the inital document - if the provider wanted you to have the content they would provide much more consumable APIs to it, or you would be google.

Comment: Maybe http://LetMeUser594166ThatForYou.com ???   Probably not catchy enough.

Comment: what happens if you visit the site with javascript disabled? does the HTML include what you need? thats what the server sends upon first request.

Answer (score 0):

Its not likely server-side cause when you view source the server side is already complete and rendered. That said they may have scripts that dynamically change the the contents of the page after the load has been completed, which if its changing after load is complete and all has originally been rendered your stuck with what was originally rendered as far as the source goes not anything there after. Some browsers have the ability to keep up with the rendering and manipulations going on but theres a lot going on in the application that makes the browser do that, thats not in any way related to JavaScript.

Another plausible concept or 2 is. They have something built in somewhere on the site for XSS detection of some sort. If a refering script isn't on the domain itself then its going to see whatever they want it to. Or.. Your script is suffering from the "same origin policy" that could be mucking it up some how. Or like someone else said your not parsing the DOM right.

You could try loading the page up in an iframe on your site then getting the innerHTML of the iframe then dumping that into a file or something.

Answer (score 0):

They may just be adding in certain content based on browser id (user-agent) strings.

Try setting your user agent to this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
```